# Ruby on Rails App Displaying Unwanted Data

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, join

Whenever the following code runs i get extra output on the page which looks like the garbage on the bottom.  I have tried to see if it is in my migrations or function calls, but they all seem to be pretty clean (not much too f.name).  If needed I can provide a copy of my migrations and schema.

```
<%= @subject.Name %>
<%= @subject.formulas.each do |f| %>
  <div class="entry">
    <h3><%= f.name %></h3>  
  </div>
<% end %>
```

The extra output is:

```
[#<Formula id: 2, name: "Pythagorean Theorem", description: "n any right triangle, the area of the square whose ...", formula: "a^2+b^2=c^2", created_at: "2011-05-17 03:18:44", updated_at: "2011-05-17 03:18:44">]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change

```
<%= @subject.formulas.each do |f| %>
```

to

```
<% @subject.formulas.each do |f| %>
```

Comment: thank you very much, its amazing how often you forget the little things